# Help with multiplying by the conjugate

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How in the world does $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{1+\sqrt{3}}$ simplify to $2-\sqrt{3}$?

I'm stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We take advantage of the difference of squares identity: $$(a+b)(a-b) = a^2-b^2$$ and we do this by multiplying the numerator *and* denominator by the *conjugate* of the *denominator*. In this case, we multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt 3 - 1$:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt 3 + 1}&=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt 3 + 1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt 3 - 1}{\sqrt 3 - 1} \\ \\ &= \frac{(\sqrt 3 -1)^2}{(\sqrt 3)^2 - 1^2} \\ \\ &= \frac{3-2\sqrt3 + 1}{3-1} \\ \\ &= \frac{4 - 2\sqrt 3}2 \\ \\ & = 2-\sqrt 3\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The moment you see a $ a + \sqrt b $ in the denominator you should think of multiplying numerator and denominator with $ a - \sqrt b $  so that you are left with $ (a^2 - b^2) $ in the denominator.This is called rationalization of the denominator.

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt 3 + 1}$$

$$=\frac{(\sqrt 3 -1)^2}{3 - 1 } $$

$$ =\dfrac{4-2 \sqrt 3 }{2}$$

$$= (2-\sqrt 3 ). $$